# esc_html__() cuts string on space character

Tags: php, wordpress

The situation is like this:

```
$widgetInputCompanyName = '<div class="widget"><input class="widget-input" type="text" name="subject" placeholder=' . esc_html__( "Your company name", "fbstax" ) . ' required></div>';
```

So in placeholder only Your is displayed. Why? If change it to other string with space character it will display only first word.

Comment: which version are you using? and what's "fbstax" used for domain?

Comment: 7.1 and 'fbstax' is for domain

Comment: For the next time, if you stumble across such a problem, inspect the generated source code and not just what the browser renders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a minute to find out why, but it's because you haven't put any quotes around the placeholder attribute so the `company` and `name` words are treated like attributes of the element.

Easy to miss. This is the working code:

```
$widgetInputCompanyName = '<div class="widget"><input class="widget-input" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="' . esc_html__( "Your company name", "fbstax" ) . '" required></div>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was so obvious!

Answer (score 0):

try the following:-

```
$widgetInputCompanyName = '<div class="widget"><input class="widget-input" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="' . esc_html__( "Your company name", "fbstax" ) . '" required></div>';
```

We need to use "" for attribute value as placeholder="some value",

you were using placeholder=some value